# Did Steve Jobs ever thank the Apple II team?

Tags: steve-jobs

In the 2015 film *Steve Jobs*, a running story throughout the movie has Seth Rogen's character Steve Wozniak asking Steve Jobs to publicly thank the Apple II team for their work.

At the end of the film they have a full blown argument about this before the iMac launch, but the movie ends before we actually see the launch itself. In real life, did Steve Jobs ever actually thank the Apple II team at the iMac launch?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remember, Aaron Sorkin said himself the script was entirely fictional. I think he even said something like "if any of the lines were said in real life" that's a nice coincidence.

That being said, if you watch the old Apple events he doesn't thank the Apple II team. However he may have never been asked to thank them as the film portrays, more than likely this is the case.

You also have to remember he was stubborn, a genius but stubborn and he had been trying to create a new path for Apple with Macintosh etc. and so no doubt he would have harboured no great gratitude towards Apple II.

Comment: Macintosh is a computer, Mackintosh was a famous Scottish artist and architect.

Comment: "the script was entirely fictional". Makes me glad I never wasted any time watching it then.

Comment: @Hannover. I think you will be pleasantly surprised if you do decide to watch it. IT was ... touching.